# what is the spindle speed of the western digital green 1TB drive?

Tags: hard-drive

i was curious what is the spindle of the western digital green 1TB drive
[link text](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.asp?driveid=576)

its not written anywhere and i believe its less then 7200 but how much ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it's 7200RPM:

```
Storage Hard Drive


Buffer Size:             32 MB
Capacity:                1 TB
Compliant Standards:     S.M.A.R.T.
Data Transfer Rate:      300 MBps
Features:                IntelliPark, IntelliPower (5400-7200), IntelliSeek, 
                         Perpendicular Magnetic Recording (PMR), StableTrac
Form Factor:             3.5" x 1/3H
Form Factor (Short):     3.5"
Hard Drive Type:         Internal hard drive
Interface:               Serial ATA-300
Interface Type:          Serial ATA-300
Non-Recoverable Errors:  1 per 10^15
Spindle Speed:           7200 rpm
Start Stop Cycles:       300,000
```

[CDW Canada](http://www.cdw.ca/shop/products/default.aspx?edc=1665316&enkwrd=ALLPROD%3aWD10EADS): info is under Technical Specifications.

Comment: It says "IntelliPower (5400-7200)", does that mean the speed changes? (also it's "you're", not "your")

Comment: i think its variable speed
anyway i like this drive since it dont get hot and so it will live longer then a black or blue one :)

Comment: Well it turns out "YOU'RE" correct davr. 
Who knew...
http://www.seagate.com/docs/pdf/whitepaper/mb_intellipower_exposed.pdf

According to the "anti- marketing" of the competition - Intellipower is a fancy word for slow. 
Read the PDF at that link and it will explain. 

News to me, but informative.

Comment: davr is correct on this. The green drives are variable speed drives.

Comment: @Holmes, WD an Seagate are same company :)

Comment: @Artem Tikhomirov Err... no they're not.

Comment: @Artem: Seagate bought Maxtor several years ago. WD is not the same company as Seagate.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliPower drives' speed is fixed between 5400 and 7200 an manufacturing time. Actiual speed is determined as result of power consumption, noise and head emission testing.

[see](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/AAG/ENG/2178-701080.pdf)